# How to make the plus sign show for a variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, binomial-coefficients

#### I am currently working on a program in Python that will factor trinomial equations into binomial equations. However, the problem is that whenever I calculate the binomials, if it is positive then the + sign will not show up. For example, when I input 2 for b and -15 for c I get the output

> The binomials are: (x-3)(x5)

#### As you can see, the + sign does not show for the second binomial. How can I fix this?

#### Here is my code:

```
import math
print " This program will find the binomials of an equation."
a = int(raw_input('Enter the first coefficient'))
b = int(raw_input('Enter the second coefficient'))
c = int(raw_input('Enter the third term'))
firstbinomial=str(int((((b*-1)+math.sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a))*-1))
secondbinomial=str(int((((b*-1)-math.sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a))*-1))  
print"The binomials are: (x"+firstbinomial+")(x"+secondbinomial")"
```

#### I have tried doing:

```
import math
    print " This program will find the binomials of an equation."
    a = int(raw_input('Enter the first coefficient'))
    b = int(raw_input('Enter the second coefficient'))
    c = int(raw_input('Enter the third term'))
    firstbinomial=str(int((((b*-1)+math.sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a))*-1))
if firstbinomial<=0:
     sign=""
else:
     sign="+"
    secondbinomial=str(int((((b*-1)-math.sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a))*-1))  
if secondbinomial<=0:
     sign=""
else:
     sign="+"
    print"The binomials are: (x"+sign+firstbinomial+")(x"+sign+secondbinomial")"
```

#### However I ended up getting:

> The binomials are: (x+-3)(x+5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use string formatting to show positive signs, or explicitly use `+` in the string:

```
firstbinomial =  (((b * -1) + math.sqrt((b ** 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)) * -1
secondbinomial = (((b * -1) - math.sqrt((b ** 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)) * -1

print "The binomials are: (x{:+.0f})(x{:+.0f})".format(firstbinomial, secondbinomial)

# prints "The binomials are: (x-3)(x+5)"
```

(which leaves the values as floats but formats without the decimal point), or

```
print "The binomials are: (x+{})(x+{})".format(firstbinomial, secondbinomial)

# prints "The binomials are: (x+-3)(x+5)"
```

The `-` only shows because negative values are always printed with their sign.

Answer (score 3):

You should use string formatting to produce your output. Numbers can be given the `"+"` formatting option to always show their signs, rather than only showing for negatives:

```
print "The binomials are: (x{:+})(x{:+})".format(firstbinomial, secondbinomial)
```

This requires that you skip calling `str` on the integer value you calculate for `firstbinomial` and `secondbinomial` on the previous lines.

If you needed the values (with their signs) as strings, an alternative might be to use the `format` function rather than `str`:

```
firstbinomial = format(int((((b*-1)+math.sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a))*-1), "+")
```

Comment: Note that the OP is converting the binomials to strings.